# Recurring Email with Voting buttons VBA

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm looking to setup a VBS / WSH / BAT script to allow a user to schedule an email every other day to send with voting buttons attached.

I found an old script that seems to do what i need but keep getting the error

Error: Object Required: 'Recipients'
Code: 800A01A8

```
Dim olApplication
Dim olMail

Set olApplication = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = olApplication.CreateItem(0)

With olMail
  .Subject = "Subject line"
  .Body = "Any text you might want to include."
  .Recipients.Add("UserA;UserB;UserC")
  .VotingOptions = "Available Immediately;Available Soon;Unavailable"
End With

If Recipients.ResolveAll Then
  olMail.Send
End If
```

Any ideas where im going wrong?

Comment: Do you really pass multiple recipients to Recipients.Add? Either call Recipients.Add for each recipient, or set the To property to a ";" separated list of names or addresses.

Comment: I tried this with only one single recipient using both the email address and the user ID and it still throws that error

Comment: What happens if you set the To property instead?

Comment: If i set .to it throws the error "Object Required: 'Recipients'"

Comment: How can it throw that error if you were to set the To property? olMail.To = "UserA;UserB;UserC"

Comment: **With olMail
  .Subject = "Subject line"
  .Body = "Any text you might want to include."
  .To = "user@user.com"
  .VotingOptions = "Available Immediately;Available Soon;Unavailable"
End With**

Still throws the same error and leaves me scratching my head

Answer (score 0):

Is Outlook running at the time your code is executed? Try to add the a call o Namespace.Logon:

```
Set olApplication = WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set olNS = olApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olNS.Logon
Set olMail = olApplication.CreateItem(0)
```

Comment: Outlook is running, and with the addition of that code it still throws the error even if i replace .To with .Recipients.Add("email@email.com")

Comment: Wait a second. Is the error raised when you add a recipient? Or when you call Recipients.ResolveAll? Either move it to inside the "with" block and change it to "If olMail.Recipients.ResolveAll Then"